# Android Market applicatin top, filtered by country

Tags: google-play-store

Android Market has an application top (free and paid apps), but it seems it is universal since in the top I see many apps in different languages.

Is there a way to see these tops by "market"? (by this I mean country, for instance France). It would be extremely interesting to see how an app is positionning itself on its market, and I guess for the users it would be extremely welcome to be able to see what's hot in their country.

Does anyone know the status of such a feature, or if there is a way to access all these data by a specific country filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AppBrain.

Up right menu. Press "More" -> "Popular in ... (I'm not sure translation)" -> country

Example for Poland http://www.appbrain.com/apps/country-poland/